# Regex to escape the parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried different ways to escape the parentheses using regex in JavaScript but I still can't make it work.

This is the string:

```
"abc(blah (blah) blah()...).def(blah() (blah).. () ...)"
```

I want this to be detected:

```
abc().def()
```

Using this code, it returns false.

```
 str.match(/abc\([^)]*\)\.def\([^)]*\)/i);
```

Can you please tell me why my regex is not working?

Comment: Are you sure? It returns `["abc(blah blah blah).def(blah blah...)"]` for me.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have just edited the post. Basically it has nested parentheses.

Comment: What do you mean you want it "to be detected"? You mean you want to pull out the `abc().def()` text and do something with it? Or you just want your regex to match the "abc(blah (blah) ... etc" string?

Comment: Agreed: '_I want this to be detected_ ' makes no sense to me.

Comment: Hmm. what I mean is: I want the whole string to be matched.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This regex will match the string you provided:

```
(abc\().+(\)\.def\().+(\))
```

And using backreferences `$1$2$3` will produce `abc().def()`

Or just use this if you don't want the back references:

```
abc\(.+\)\.def\(.+\)
```

Answer (score 0):

K... Here's an Idea...

```
abc(blah (blah) blah()).def(blah() (blah).blah())
```

Use regExp like this

```
var regExp1 = \^([a-z])*\(\ig;
```

it'll match

```
abc(
```

then use

```
var regExp2 = /\)\./
```

it'll match the

```
")."
```

in the string..

then split the actual string so that it becomes

```
def(blah() (blah).blah())
```

repeat till the regular expression can't find the

```
regExp2
```

and add a closing bracket..
The simplest solution I could think of..
Hope it helps..